# MySQL does not import a .sql

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a `.sql` that I've downloaded. The thing is that when I click on continue, it gets in white page and does not import the database.

I've tried importing my code too in the option SQL but doesn't work either.

I get this error:
https://gyazo.com/a864ad63b66259235fb4d7493344fcd2

Here's a video I've recorded for you, so you will understand better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZVtxzCMjm8

Comment: You need to select an existing database or need to create a database first. And then try to import.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering that fast!

I've tried making first the database and then importing; doesn't work neither, i still havve the same issue. 

Even the sql file has a code that says if the database doesn't exist, then make one.

Comment: Did you make the database and then did you select the database? And then click the import?

Comment: Yes. Maybe is because i had to change a file because i was getting an error.
Had to do this
https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn/%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89-bug-phpmyadmin-php7-2-ubuntu-16-04-92b287090b01

Comment: Can you post the SQL code in the SQL file?

Comment: No, I get another issue:
https://gyazo.com/603492a0bbd50d1f8f4237869e0fabff

Comment: Actually, I do not understand your language.  Can you post that in English?

Comment: Here you have in english
https://gyazo.com/a864ad63b66259235fb4d7493344fcd2

Comment: I got this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587227/phpmyadmin-error-in-processing-request-error-code-500-error-text-internal-serv

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed my issue.
https://gyazo.com/fae77830720aa40af83a63f981c59a47

How can i give you a +1 or something?

Comment: I have updated this as an answer.

Comment: @Kashix. I believe that Hasitha's answer worked for you. Could you mark the below answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select an existing database or need to create a database first. And then try to import.

**Update**

For the new error that you got, you can follow this.

[phpMyAdmin Error in processing request Error code: 500 Error text: Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587227/phpmyadmin-error-in-processing-request-error-code-500-error-text-internal-serv)

And also I suggest updating your `xampp` or `wamp` will also solve this problem.